# HighChart legend I override mouseover but loose transparency functionality. How do I keep it?

Tags: highcharts

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
     events: {
       afterAnimate: function () {
         for (let item of this.chart.legend.allItems) {
           item.legendItem.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                /**
                 * Register a callback based on the legend selected
                 */
           }).on('mouseout', function (e) {
                /**
                 * Degerister a callback
           })
         }
       }
     },
```

I wish to add functionality when I mouseover the legend item but the above removes the default transparency functionality.  How can I easily re-invoke?

Comment: Hi @joe, Everything seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4994/ Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Comment: hi @ppotaczek I haven't a clue right now to be honest as the config I have is very large and based on your example I must have something enabled that is creating an issue.  I will continue to investigate my setup and once I figure out more details will let you know.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek  in the legend object i have useHTML flag set to true and that is the root cause.  I have that flag enabled to use the labelFormatter with  labelFormatter: function () {
      return `<svg style="${symbolSvgStyle}">
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke=${this.color} stroke-width="1" fill=${this.color} />
  </svg>  ${this.name}`
    },

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hfjngc5a/ modified your example and added legend with useHTML.  Notice transparency no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a part of default code for the events functions:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    events: {
      afterAnimate: function() {
        const legend = this.chart.legend,
          boxWrapper = legend.chart.renderer.boxWrapper;

        for (let item of legend.allItems) {
          let isPoint = item instanceof Highcharts.Point,
            activeClass = 'highcharts-legend-' +
            (isPoint ? 'point' : 'series') + '-active';

          item.legendItem.on('mouseover', function(e) {
            if (item.visible) {
              legend.allItems.forEach(function(inactiveItem) {
                if (item !== inactiveItem) {
                  inactiveItem.setState('inactive', !isPoint);
                }
              });
            }
            item.setState('hover');

            if (item.visible) {
              boxWrapper.addClass(activeClass);
            }

          }).on('mouseout', function(e) {
            legend.allItems.forEach(function(inactiveItem) {
              if (item !== inactiveItem) {
                inactiveItem.setState('', !isPoint);
              }
            });

            boxWrapper.removeClass(activeClass);
            item.setState();
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/5000/

Comment: Thanks so much!  I will apply your recommendation and see how it works!